# image upload with some data using angularjs and asp .net mvc web api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have tried many tutorial but found nothing fruitful to be successful!
I want to send some data with a image to asp web api. 
What i got now is that : http://www.encodedna.com/angularjs/tutorial/angularjs-file-upload-using-http-post-formdata-webapi.htm
I can now save image using that tutorial but when i try to send some value with that image it returns 'internal server error';

My web api:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/PictureAttApi/savepic")]
    public string savepic()
    {



        int iUploadedCnt = 0;

        // DEFINE THE PATH WHERE WE WANT TO SAVE THE FILES.
        string sPath = "";
        sPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/images/");

        System.Web.HttpFileCollection hfc = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

        // CHECK THE FILE COUNT.
        for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt <= hfc.Count - 1; iCnt++)
        {
            System.Web.HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[iCnt];

            if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // CHECK IF THE SELECTED FILE(S) ALREADY EXISTS IN FOLDER. (AVOID DUPLICATE)
                if (!File.Exists(sPath + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)))
                {
                    // SAVE THE FILES IN THE FOLDER.
                    hpf.SaveAs(sPath + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                    iUploadedCnt = iUploadedCnt + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        // RETURN A MESSAGE.
        if (iUploadedCnt > 0)
        {
            return iUploadedCnt + " Files Uploaded Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Upload Failed";
        }
    }
```

My js:

```
 $scope.addimagefunc=function(){

//    var data = new FormData($('form')[0]);

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('picture', $scope.picture);
    data.append('FatherName', '5555');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: dataUrl + 'PictureAttApi/savepic',    // CALL WEB API TO SAVE THE FILES.
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,         // PREVENT AUTOMATIC DATA PROCESSING.
            cache: false,
            data: data,                 // DATA OR FILES IN THIS CONTEXT.
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                $('#output').text(data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

}

My directive:

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

My HTML:

```
  <form action="">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="EmpPicture" class="">Upload Image:</label>
        <input type="file" id="inputDeImg" ng-model="EmpPictureAdd" name="EmpPicture" file-model="picture" accept="image/*" />

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="#" id="dImg" />
    </div>

  <input class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addimagefunc()" value="add" />

    <p id="output"></p>
</form>
```

But when i add this:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/PictureAttApi/savepic")]
     public string savepic(Member m)
        {

}
```

it returns internal error:
My quest is without any parameter(HTTPPostrdFileBase) how the image is saved?
How can i pass some data(like $scope.FatherName) with image in apiController?

Comment: what error exactly are you getting please tell me?

Comment: Internal server error! try to understand, i need to pass data through parameter in controller function

Answer (score 0):

For simple data you might find it easiest to pass it along in the uri

So on javascript side, change the url in the $ajax to this

```
url: dataUrl + 'PictureAttApi/savepic?FatherName=55555'
```

And Server side:

```
public string savepic([FromUri]string FatherName){
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But how can i send multiple value with images? It works with image now. but i have to send values like ''FatherName' 'MotherName','BirthDate','JoinDate' etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example in the link that you have shared, you can "append" more values to the "formdata". For example,

*Controller*

```
$scope.getTheFiles = function ($files) {
angular.forEach($files, function (value, key) {
    formdata.append(key, value);                    // IMAGES 
    formdata.append('fatherName', 'somevalue');    // SOME OTHER DATA
});
```

};

*Web API*

Read the value in your Web API using,

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
```

This way you can simultaneously upload multiple files and pass some values along with it.